# Chrome (android) how to allow playing audio without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

I am developing a web application with HTML and Javascript and one of the functions of that web applications is that it alerts user with blinking and **audio signal** when certain events happen.

Sometimes users would just have that webapp open and not interact with it, only waiting for alert. The problem here is, that chrome doesn't allow sound, until user have already interacted with webpage, so I cannot alert users with audio signal.

Is there a way to bypass this? Is there a way to allow this in Google Chrome settings? It would be okay if it would be on a local level only, as said application will only be running on a few Android tablets on a Google Chrome.

edit:
code for playing sound:

```
let audio = new Audio('Sound/gentle_sms.mp3');

function PlaySound()
{
    audio.loop=true;
    audio.play();
}

function StopSound()
{
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
}
```

function PlaySound() is called from socket event listener

Comment: Pls share your code for playing the sound.

Comment: @ArchitGargi I added the code

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question can not be solved. A Website can never overrule or bypass browser settings of a user. If a website could take control and overrule use settings, then this would be a seriose security risk! Trying to bypass or hack it has no ethical worth for this site.

Comment: @tacoshy You misunderstand, I am asking if there is a way to make settings in browser manually so that website will work as intended, not that website would change browser settings

Comment: Then this question would be no programming question and as such be off-topic for SO.

Comment: @tacoshy That is an *answer*, not a close reason.  Though I separately agree that changing browser settings, as clarified by the comments, is off-topic here.